# PHP barchart that display variance

Tags: php, bar-chart

meanwhile I've been looking for hours for an php barchart module which not only displays bars but also the variance of the corresponding values in form of a little dash above the bars?

I found this entry in stackoverflow: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/110839/best-graph-and-diagram-toolset-for-php - but it did not help

At the moment I'm using the jpgraph_bar.php module of jpgprah: http://jpgraph.net/features/src/show-example.php?target=new_bar3.php

However, it did not support variance information. The feature of the error plot, also listed in the jpgraph repository, would be fine to be in displayed in the barchart: http://jpgraph.net/features/gallery.php#error1

Any ideas where to look at or how can I merge this modules?

EDIT:

Here is an example what I'm looking for: http://www.graphpad.com/prism/tutorials/data_entry/Barchart.gif.

Answer (score 1):

Try the [google chart api](http://code.google.com/apis/chart/)

I'm not sure they can do what you want, but they are very simple to use and with a good costumization..

You can choose between many kind of chart (Pie, Line, Column, Area, Tree, Controls and more)..

**EDIT**

After rapid look, seems that this apis supports variance :)

Comment: Thanks, however I did not find the variance support :-)

Comment: are you looking for this? http://code.google.com/apis/chart/image/docs/gallery/compound_charts.html#gcharts_candlestick_markers

Comment: Thanks Marcx, the candlestick bars are nearly good... but, The candlestick bar would be fine, if the bar would begin at 0...